# why does my routes give me wrong direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a association between user, store and item like this:

```
user has one store
store has many items
item belongs to store
```

So when I create item it must belongs to the current user's store

Now, I logged in as user_1 , I want to search for user_2's item. But if I didn't create user_1's store, It keep redirecting me to localhost:3000/stores

in items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit]
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @items = Item.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end    

    if params[:category]

        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id

        @items = Item.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end


end

def show
end

def new
    @store = current_user.store
    @item = @store.items.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] } 
end

def update
     @item.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @item.update(item_params)
        redirect_to item_path(@item)
    else 
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def create
    @store = current_user.store 
    @item = @store.items.build(item_params)
    @item.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @item.save
       flash[:success] = "Creating item success"
       redirect_to @item    
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:code, :name, :description, :producer,  :item_img, :store_id,
    :category_id  )
end

def find_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end

def find_user
    @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id]) 
end

end
```

in stores_controller.rb:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :find_user

def show         

    if current_user.store.blank?
        redirect_to new
    else
        @items = Item.where(store_id: @store.id)   
    end               
end

def index    
    @stores = Store.all.order("created at DESC")    
end

def new
    @store = current_user.build_store
end

def create 
    @store = current_user.build_store(store_params)
    if @store.save
        session[:store_id] = @store.id
       flash[:success] = "Creating item success"
       redirect_to @store, notice: 'success'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private 



def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit( :name , :user_id)
end

def find_store
    @store = Store.find(params[:id])
end

def find_user
    @user = Store.find_by(params[:user_id])
end

end
```

The error raised whenever I click on the button in items/show.html.erb.
In items/show.html.erb:

```
<button>see more item from:<%= link_to @item.store.name, store_path(@item.store.id)%></button>
```

in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
resources :items
resources :stores
```

In the show method for stores_controller, I still want to load the current_user's store in navbar section to make sure he can add more items to his store when he logged in.

I'm still a newbie in rails and I'm looking for solutions to solve this problem :-)

Comment: The problem is that your `find_user` method needs a param of `user_id` to be passed, but you're not passing it anywhere. Try to comment out the `before_action :find_user` you should not need this because you can always get the user from the store object.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question, but It still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a store requires a user_id then you don't need `before_action :find_user` because you can get the store's user just by calling `store.user`

It looks like you require the `current_user` to have a store but what if they are not logged in?  Shouldn't it be this?

```
def show         
  if current_user && current_user.store.blank?
    redirect_to new
  else
    @items = Item.where(store_id: @store.id)   
  end               
end
```